# Why does bcp output null when the column contains an empty string and empty string when the column is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, bcp

This struck me as really weird behaviour and I spent a while checking for bugs in my code before I found this

"out copies from the database table or view to a file. If you specify an existing file, the file is overwritten. When extracting data, note that the bcp utility represents an empty string as a null and a null string as an empty string." (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Obviously this allowed me to fix my problem but can anybody think of or does anybody know a reason why this is the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588149/how-to-make-microsoft-bcp-export-empty-string-instead-of-a-nul-char provides a potential solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been some time, but I'm sure it's a backwards compatibility/legacy back to SQL Server 6.5

SQL Server 6.5 could not store empty string: there was always one space. This changed with SQL 7

So `'' -> NULL` and `' ' -> ''` is correct from an ancient history perspective.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ARTICULO as Articulo, 
        case when rtrim(CCOLOR) = '' then null else rtrim(CCOLOR) end as Color, 
        case when rtrim(TALLE) = '' then null else rtrim(TALLE) end as Talle,
from precios
```

Send `null` in place of empty.

I find the best solution here:

https://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143738-bcp-inserting-blank-space-empty-string

> I found a work around, using a Case structure in the sql query to
>   change empty string to a null. The BCP in turn outputs the resulting
>   null as an empty!
>   Thanks for your assistance.
>   Eric

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the "default values" section for BCP:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server

> For example, if there is a null field in a data file, the default value for the column is loaded instead.

You have to think back to days where importing plain text files from other weird systems. BCP translates `''` as "not defined"(=missing data) and sets a NULL in the database (=missing data). The other way around a NULL from database must be a `''` for the other systems.

To get the 'real' data out of the database use the `-k` switch:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-nulls-or-use-default-values-during-bulk-import-sql-server#keep_nulls

> The following qualifiers specify that an empty field in the data file retains its null value during the bulk-import operation, rather than inheriting a default value (if any) for the table columns.

Then you have your ASCII 0x0 in your file/database.