# How to make Microsoft BCP export empty string instead of a NUL char?

Tags: sql, t-sql, bcp

I was working trying to get this bcp tool to work in a particular way. The -c switch is supposed to export using chars, but for some reason there was a weird char showing in Notepad++ like if it was UNICODE or some other formatting.

I wanted to get that char, which was an Empty string in the database, to export as an empty string into the text file. How do you do that?

Comment: Similar question [Why does bcp output null when the column contains an empty string and empty string when the column is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644731/why-does-bcp-output-null-when-the-column-contains-an-empty-string-and-empty-stri).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, after looking around the web this is what I found. Thought to put it in SO so more people have access to it.

http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-sql-server/147106-how-export-empty-strings-via-bcp.html

> But when I run bcp, the empty strings are written to the text file
>   using the ASCII "NUL" character (0x0). Instead, I want the field to be
>   filled with blanks (0x20).

Solution:

> In a text file, an empty string is interpreted as NULL when you bulk
>   in data. The NUL character is interpreted as the empty string, so
>   there is consistency. But that does not help much if you are exporting
>   data to another system....

Simply wrap around a `NULLIF` that field that is possibly empty in the database and make it catch `''` and replace with `NULL`. That will get converted into ^^values^^^^more values^^and more^^ so you get double separator with an blank instead of the NUL character.

E.g.:

```
...
NULLIF(pri.InstanceName, '') as PerformanceInstanceName,
...
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: there is a switch for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441273/1498669

Comment: @Bernhard Which switch is that? For *export*

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow-up...

The `NULLIF` solution above works fine in Microsoft SQL, but for a more standardized solution that works in almost any Database you should try `COALESCE`.

The syntax is very similar:

```
COALESCE(pri.InstanceName, '') as PerformanceInstanceName
```

Comment: Actually, COALESCE is the opposite of what's needed in this case. We need to identify nulls and replace with a '''

Comment: that's what i thought, but when i changed from `coalesce` to `nullif` they null output was replaced by an empty string