# SQL output Custom Delimiter

Tags: sql

How do I create my SQL output like the following. (with `,` delimiter)

```
"1","FUZION",""
```

http://postimg.org/image/xehmnq5g5/

Comment: What RDBMS/tool are you using?

Comment: are you looking for csv output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079666/how-to-produce-an-csv-output-file-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the below script.

```
DECLARE @MyOrderList VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @MyOrderList = ''
SELECT @MyOrderList = ISNULL(@MyOrderList ,'') +  '"' +ColumnName + '" ,' FROM TableName

SET @MyOrderList = SUBSTRING(@MyOrderList , 1, LEN(@MyOrderList )-1)
SELECT @MyOrderList
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are selecting data from 3 columns -

```
col1 = '1'
col2 = 'Fuzion'
col3 = ''
```

- All 3 fields being VARCHAR & you are using SQL SERVER.

You could try something like this -

```
SELECT '"'+ISNULL(col1,'')+'","'+ISNULL(col2,'')+'","'+ISNULL(col3,'')+'"'
```

**Note** - If any of your field is not a VARCHAR - cast it to VARCHAR and then concatenate.

Comment: by using -s "," in SQLCMD, my output result like the following 1,FUZION. All i want is "1","FUZION". Thanks

Comment: However, I managed to get it done by the following query Select
  MerchantID = +'"' + Convert(varchar(20),microsdb.CHECKS.RevCtrID) + '"',
  DeviceSN = +'"' + Convert(varchar(20),microsdb.CHECKS.LastWorkstationID) +
  '"', Many Thanks guys for the reference