# Exporting query output to csv automatically

Tags: sql-server, csv, save

I'd like to save the output of queries in SQL Server 2014 to csv files, but I'd like it to be automatic.
Is that possible?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using to execute your queries?

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079666/how-to-produce-an-csv-output-file-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server.  I would suggest that if you can wrap all of this up in a stored procedure then you could use SQL Agent to schedule it, then it would be automatic?