# Ignore null's in exported .csv file, bcp utility

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, export-to-csv, bcp

> **How can I ignore null's in my exported .csv file**, I used bcp utility
>   within sql server, here it is how this looks like altogether.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('[dbo].[generateCSV]') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateCSV]
GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[generateCSV]

(
 @table varchar(100),
 @output varchar(100), 
 @date varchar(12),
 @server varchar(30)
)

AS

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + @table  + ' 
where reportingdate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  @output + '  -c 
-C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server 

 exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql 




       -- Main EXEC

EXEC dbo.generateCSV @table = 'Clients', @date = '2017-10-31', @output = 
'//172.18.16.109/share/Test.csv (server with export target location ) ', 
@server = '172.18.16.108(server we are connected to and from which we are 
taking the data)'
```

After exporting and opening my file in notepad++ empty columns end up filled with NULL's.

[image]

What I want it to look like is...

[image]

---

**Edit:**

I included *ISNULL()* in my select clause but still notepad will read those columns as null valued.

```
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select 
ReportingDate,uniqClientID,registrationNumber,name,ISNULL(vatNumber,'''') as 
vatNumber,ISNULL(entityStatusCode,'''') as entityStatusCode, 
maximumLifetimeDPD from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + 
@table  + ' where ReportingDate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  
@output + '  -c -C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server
```

Comment: Use isnull function for empty columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Microsoft BCP export empty string instead of a NUL char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588149/how-to-make-microsoft-bcp-export-empty-string-instead-of-a-nul-char)

Comment: Why don't you use SSIS and the Data Import/Export Wizard? The Wizard actually generates an SSIS package you can reuse or edit. `bcp` is a bulk tool, not a CSV import/export tool

Comment: Client demands a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select * from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + @table  +
>   '  where reportingdate = ''' + @date + '''"' + ' queryout ' +  @output
>   + '  -c 
>   -C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server

Instead of `SELECT *` write the specific column names.

Wherever you feel `NULL` can appear you can write like following.

```
....   
SELECT 
Column1,
ISNULL(Column2,'') AS Column2,
Column3,
....
 from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.' + @table 
.....
```

**Note**: If you have INT as datatype, you need to slightly change your select according to following query.

```
DECLARE @INTVAL INT
SET @INTVAL = NULL
SELECT
ISNULL(LTRIM(NULLIF(@INTVAL, 0)), '') AS ColumnName
```

Comment: Yes, this must be the only way, tried to avoid it as I have too much of those null columns.

Comment: If you don't handle it in select, by default SQL will return NULL

Comment: I have a problem.
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "select ReportingDate,uniqClientID,registrationNumber,name,ISNULL(vatNumber,'') as vatNumber ...
I get some syntax errors, unclosed quotations,but when I remove ISNULL(vatNumber,'') as vatNumber from the select clause it will work just fine.

Comment: Can you update your query in the question itself as Edit. It will help to resolve.

Comment: You can take a look.

Comment: They have to be of the same type, I can't replace column which stored int data type with an empty string.

Comment: For int use SELECT
 ISNULL(LTRIM(NULLIF(0, 0)), '') AS ColumnName

Comment: Unfortunately when I open it with notepad NULL's are still there.

Comment: @T_Dejan INSULL works. Your script though uses escaped queries inside escaped queries which means you probably don't know *what* is executed in the end. Forget about NUL, think about SQL injection attacks and someone running code with our credentials on the server because you disabled security to run `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: @T_Dejan try a *simple* example first. Run bcp from the command line wiht a simple query and ISNULL, no string concatenations. Once you get it working you can think about changing the query

Comment: Okay I got it working with NULLIF, what do you suggest on enhancing security.